# Service Account Permissions : Limiting to specific GA API

Tags: google-api

I created a [new Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) in Cloud Project, and want to restrict this account's permission to only use one specific Google API listed [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/).

Lets say my application using this service account should only be allowed to use "Google Analytics API". If possible, further limited to use subset of API requests (for ex. `analytics.management.customMetrics.list`, `analytics.management.filters.insert` etc.

I tried to create custom Role, but when I try to add necessary Permission, I don't see me desired permissions listed in that list... (attach screenshot)

> How can I restrict this Service Account permissions to specific APIs?

Also,

> does it make any difference creating new project in
>   https://console.developers.google.com/ or in
>   https://console.cloud.google.com/ ? I san see a project in both places
>   anyways...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case because you are using the Google Analytics API, there is an additional step where you need to add the Service Account to your Google Analytics account. If the Service Account is not added then it won't have access to the resources inside of Google Analytics.

See "1. Enable the API" in the following link:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

> **Add service account to the Google Analytics account**
>
> The newly created
> service account will have an email address that looks similar to:
>
> `quickstart@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
>
> Use this email address
> to add a user to the Google analytics view you want to access via the
> API. For this tutorial only Read & Analyze permissions are needed.

See the following for some guidance on managing users in Google Analytics
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702

Comment: Thanks ScottMcC for answering my question. But my questions is - how can I further limit this service account's success to only Google Analytics related API calls (I could see Big Query, Cloud Storage related permissions in that permission list, but not Google Analytics related permissions.. nor AdWords nor any of so called "Google discovery based APIs"